# how to query with mongoose timestamp date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have used mongoose-timestamp plugin https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-timestamp

Which maintains createdAt and updatedAt fields on the documents

I want to find the documents which have been updated after certain Date, how should i do that??

This is what i am doing :

```
Model.find({updatedAt : { $gte : new Date(2014, 5, 24)} }, function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs); //prints empty arry []
});
```

However i have checked in mongoose console.. i find there are documents with updatedAt fields having value of after 24May2014.

What mistake i am doing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The month parameter in the JavaScript `Date` constructor is 0-based, so you're querying for docs having an `updatedAt` value after June 24, 2014.

```
> new Date(2014, 5, 24)
Tue Jun 24 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

So your query is fine otherwise and you just need to update it to use `4` for the month:

```
Model.find({updatedAt : { $gte : new Date(2014, 4, 24)} }, function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. can you please also help me one more question.. how can i find the documents which is updated in last one hour (3600seconds)

Comment: @Koka If you search you should find the answer to that.  If not, feel free to post a new question.

Comment: here is the question .... can you help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864810/fetch-mongo-documents-updated-within-last-30-minutes