# fetch mongo documents updated within last 30 minutes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to fetch documents updated within last 30 minutes

each document has updatedAt field of Date type

I am doing the following :

```
  Model.find({
    updatedAt : { $gte : new Date(Date.now() - (30 * 60000))  } },
  function(err, docs){
     console.log(err); //null
console.log(docs); //empty array []
  });
```

But i actually i have documents which have updatedAt value within the last 30 minutes by viewing from the mongoose console.

What wrong i am doing ?

Comment: What's type of `updatedAt` field in schema?

Comment: Are you updating the updatedAt value each time you are updating the document?

Comment: Hi everyone, my apologies for bringing this question to you, after hours of finding out the issues and useless googling.. i found out that.. i was testing on a database which was not linked with this script. My above script works perfectly after linking it with right database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 Model.find({
    updatedAt : { $gte : new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 30) } },
  function(err, docs){
     console.log(err); //null
console.log(docs); //empty array []
  });
```